# im looking for a gui based app to add encryption to select files for local and uploads to google drive

Tags: server, password, encryption

Is there a app hopefully with a gui that adds encryption to just selected files?

Im looking for a gui based app to add encryption to select files for local storage and uploads to google drive as back ups. I already have the home folder encrypted from 16.04 install. what I would like to do is encrypt select files, mainly Documents, pdfs and pics, and keep a copy on my system and upload a copy to google drive or another cloud.

Basically i want to save important doc, pdfs, pic's ect. like downloaded tax forms, text doc with logs of user names and passwords, important emails, I'm doing this because over the years my family and I have accumulated a lot of user names passwords and important documents, the problem is that some go unused for so long they get lost, or you cant remember what user name or password was used for what site. I am creating a local and cloud "log" but need it encrypted because these have important info.

EX: I received my w2's the other day, I wanted to go file my taxes, I needed last years return but I didn't have a paper copy, I couldn't remember what website we used last year, and when I found a email with the "thanks for creating a acct with us" from the tax prep site, I couldn't remember the user name. I only use the site once a year. But with this encrypted FS, I could have looked up a copy of my PDF tax transcript from last year,I could have checked my text logs of websites with user name and password hints.

I only have to add to or take from the files every once in a while. i can remember the stuff i use a lot, so if it takes a few steps or min to use thats cool with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install gnupg and create a gpg key you can use thunar to add some custom actions to the right-mouse button menu (Add Encrypt GPG and Decrypt GPG actions to thunar)... e.g.

Encrypt files:

/usr/bin/xfce4-terminal -e "/usr/bin/gpg-zip -e -o %f.zip.gpg -r KEY %f"

where KEY = email_address from gpg-key

Decrypt files:

/usr/bin/xfce4-terminal -e "/usr/bin/gpg-zip -d %f"

see https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGRrV.jpg for example.